# Does totally bounded imply covering compact?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let S be totally bounded. So, $\forall\epsilon>0$, $S$ can be covered by a finite number of balls of radius $\epsilon$. Now, let $\{S_n\}$ be a cover of $S$ with open sets.  So, $S_n\cap S$ is also totally bounded by say set $U_n$ as subsets of totally bounded set is totally bounded. So, $S$ can be covered by $\cup U_n$ and as $S$ is totally bounded, we can have a finite subset of $\cup U_n$, say $U$, which covers $S$. Now, for each element of $U$, we can choose a corresponding set in $\{S_n\}$ to which it belongs. Thus, we can get a finite subset of $\{S_n\}$ that covers S.

But here I didn't require $S$ to be closed/complete. Is it necessary or does being "totally bounded" takes care of being "closed or complete"? 
Can you please tell where I went wrong.

Comment: It's hard to say where the error is because you didn't tell us what $U_n$ is. Seems likely that the error is where you say each element of $U$ is contained in some $S_n$. Anyway, what you've proved is false. For example the interval $(0,1)$ (with the standard metric) is totally bounded. Consider the open cover of $(0,1)$ by the sets $(1/n,1)$, trace through your argument in that example and you'll find the error.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich as you mentioned, Error is where I state that each element of $U$ is contained in $S_n$. Even if $S_n\cap S$ is also totally bounded by say set $U_n$, each of the element of $U_n$ may not lie in $S_n$ and hence, I can't choose $S_n$ as a corresponding set of that element. Thanks. Can you please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open interval $(0,1)$ (with the standard metric) is totally bounded but not compact (for example the intervals $(1/n,1)$ are an open cover with no finite subcover). The problem with the proof is that there's simply no reason each element of $U$ should be contained in some $S_n$.

In the proof that totally bounded plus complete implies compact we first show that any open cover has a "Lebesgue number". Which means precisely that if $(S_n)$ is an open cover and $U$ is the cover by balls of radius $\delta$, then *if* $\delta$ is small enough every element of $U$ *is* contained in some $S_n$.